# How to draw a smooth line for a polynomial fuction?

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts 4.2.3 for my web project. I need to draw a line for the following function:

```
y = 0.784·x4 - 8.662·x3 + 32.38·x2 - 46.761·x + 27.26
```

Currently, my way of doing this is to create a large number (for example: 500) of points of (x,y) and then plot it in the chart.

I would like to know whether Highcharts is able to take the above function and draw a smooth line for me.

Comment: I suggest to vote for this feature on [Highcharts UserVoice](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/3786779-function-graphing-for-mathematical-equations). Adding a comment with your example would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [spline](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/spline-chart) chart type for smooth line drawing, but you have to generate a discrete set of points:

```
series: [{
    name: 'f(x)',
    data: (function () {
        var data = [];
        for (var x = 0; x <= 50; x++) {
            data.push({
                x: x,
                y: 0.784*Math.pow(x, 4) - 8.662*Math.pow(x, 3) + 32.38*Math.pow(x, 2) - 46.761*x + 27.26
            });
        }
        return data;
    })()
}],
```

Here is a fiddle showing an example: http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/4vtmLeh5/

Comment: Thanks for chiming in! Your solution is what I already use. Good to get confirmation from you!